# $\max_i x_i\ \leq \log \sum_{i} e^{x_i}$?

Tags: inequality

Let $x = (x_1 ,\ldots, x_n)$ be a vector, then

$$\max_i x_i\ \leq \log \sum_i e^{x_i}.$$

Is this correct? How to see that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, because, for each $i$,$$x_j=\log\left(e^{x_j}\right)\leqslant\log\left(\sum_ie^{x_i}\right).$$

Comment: Using the letter $i$ as both a free variable and a bound variable in the same expression is somewhat suboptimal. To the left of $\text{“}\le \text{''},$ $i$ represents a particular index value; to the right of $\text{“} \le \text{''},$ it doesn't. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: [Yes, the claim is correct]

- $\log(x)$ is an increasing function
- $e^x$ only attains positive values.
- $\log(e^{x_i})=x_i$